# Deduced type in structured binding of unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++17, structured-bindings

I am trying to see the deduced type in structured binding for an unordered_map by using `auto`, `auto &` and `auto &&`.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <type_traits>

int main() {   

    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> m{{"a","a1"}, {"b","b1"}};

    for(auto &&  [k,v]:m)
    {
        std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(k), std::string const  >::value << '\n';
        std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(v), std::string >::value << '\n';

    }
}
```

No matter i use `for(auto [k,v]:m)` or `for(auto & [k,v]:m)` or `for(auto && [k,v]:m)`, the output is always

```
1
1
```

My questions are:

- why `decltype(k)` and `decltype(v)` is not reference type in the case of `for(auto & [k,v]:m)` or `for(auto && [k,v]:m)`?
- why `decltype(k)` is of type `const` in the case of `for(auto [k,v]:m)`?

Comment: @JHBonarius Note that `decltype` has special rules when used on a structured binding: *"1) If the argument is an unparenthesized id-expression naming a structured binding, then decltype yields the referenced type (described in the specification of the structured binding declaration)."*  ("*referenced type*" is described in more detail [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding).)

Comment: For the second question simplified answer is this: because this code `iterator->first = "abc";` should not compile.

Comment: @0x5453 i read clean over it thx... was almost there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Question 1)
Like specified [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype)

> 1) If the argument is an unparenthesized id-expression naming a structured binding, then decltype yields the *referenced* type (described in the specification of the structured binding declaration).

and [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding):

> Case 2: binding a tuple-like type 
>   [...]
>   The referenced type for the i-th identifier is `std::tuple_element<i, E>::type`.

A `std::pair` (see answer to question 2) is effectively a tuple of 2. Thus it is 'tuple-*like*'.

Thus in this case the base type of Key and T are always returned (yielded).

Question 2)
Internally the [`unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) is allocated as a `std::pair<const Key, T>`. Hence, the k is `const`.

Comment: So std::pair is tuple like type?